# Master Instance Group: Exceeded EC2 Instance Quota

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am getting this error `Master Instance Group: Exceeded EC2 Instance Quota`, when I create a new cluster on Amazon EMR with 1 Master node only or 1 Master and 2 Core nodes. However, there are no EC2 instances running on my account.

What should I do? I raised a ticket, asking if I can get a quicker solution here.

Comment: Limits are regional. You can check what your current EC2 limits are in us-east-1, for example, at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Limits:

Comment: Were you launching as Spot pricing? What does your **Limits** page say?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think you are trying to access a new region or new instance type, AWS sometimes does that when you are in free tier, they allow access to 2-3 regions or free instance types only. Then you have to request access from AWS by raising a case.

But in Normal scenario, this is what happens:

You may face an error like `Exceeded EC2 Instance Quota` while you are trying to spin up new instances either standalone or in cluster.
This error is caused because you have hit the limit on number of instances allowed in your AWS account.

This limit is region and instance size specific. To get rid of this error you will have to request Amazon to increase the EC2 instance limit.

Requesting a limit increase is simple. Below are the steps:

Most service limit increases can be requested through the **AWS Support Center** by choosing **Create Case** and then choosing **Service Limit Increase**.
Most service limits are specific to a particular AWS Region, so be sure to submit a request for each Region you plan to use. Many services support requesting multiple limit increases for the same service through one support case. After creating your first request, choose **Add another request** and then choose a new limit type or Region.